# Paypal checkout does not have IPN feature

Tags: javascript, paypal

I am looking at PayPal Checkout as described at  [Sample code for PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client). There are only 2 JavaScript methods involved with this form of PayPal payment page, which are *createOrder* and *onApprove*.

I was expecting a way of specifying IPN which is easily available with PayPal Standard button.

**Question**

Is IPN feature available in PayPal Checkout and if no, then what would be the best way of implementing something like IPN?

I am thinking of using sample code as below to mimic IPN feature functionality.

```
onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                    // Show a success message to the buyer
                    //alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');

                    //IPN implementation as below
                    //Instead of showing a message to the buyer, redirect to a success page
                    //and pass query string variables to pass data from payment page top success page
                    window.location = "https://www.somesitexyzabc.com/success?s=1&d=abc";
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPN is very old. PayPal Checkout with Orders v2 doesn't use IPN. There's no purpose for it.

To record transactions on your server, do the capture on your server.

You'll need two routes, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls

Pair your two routes with the following approval code: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

When a capture is successful within your server, do whatever you need to do with the information you have before returning the JSON to the onApprove function.

Comment: Thankyou. It seems that in PayPal Checkout unlike PayPal Standard, the payment page is on the customer's website and not on PayPal's side. If that's correct, then we know if payment has succeeded if onApprove function gets executed. Is that right? Then, my suggested approach would also work.

Comment: The onApprove function and `actions.order.capture()` is client-side code. Use the server integration for notification.

Comment: In my original sample code at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client, there is no url being fetched in OnApprove function.  But in the sample code you mentioned, there is a url. This is confusing since I am not sure if a url needs to be fetched in OnApprove function?

Comment: I think in your answer you have mentioned a solution using server-side code, but in the sample code I have in my question only client-side code is used. So it appears that I could simply go with client-side code only for paypal checkout rather than server-side code to call PayPal API. Is that correct?

Comment: Do not depend on the client to notify your server after a transaction has completed.